# Um único script para N formularios

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Preciso saber qual a maneira correta para quando eu enviar um formulário um único script resolva, o código abaixo só funciona seu eu criar um script para cada formulário. Como resolvo isso?

Exemplo: `$("#meuform")` ... `$("#meuform2")` ... `$("#meuform3")`, etc.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title> teste </title>
    <meta name="" content="" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".resultado").hide();
            $("#meuform").ajaxForm({
                target: '.resultado',
                success: function(retorno){
                     $(".resultado").html(retorno);
                     $(".resultado").show();
                     $("#meuform").resetForm();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".resultado").hide();
            $("#meuform2").ajaxForm({
                target: '.resultado',
                success: function(retorno){
                     $(".resultado").html(retorno);
                     $(".resultado").show();
                     $("#meuform2").resetForm();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".resultado").hide();
            $("#meuform3").ajaxForm({
                target: '.resultado',
                success: function(retorno){
                     $(".resultado").html(retorno);
                     $(".resultado").show();
                     $("#meuform3").resetForm();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="resultado"> aqui é o reultado</div>
    <div class="formulario">
        <form method="POST" action="processafrm.php?var=10" id="meuform">
            nome:<br />
            <input type="text" name="nome" size="50" /><br />
            Email:<br />
            <input type="text" name="email" size="50" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enivar dados" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="formulario">
        <form method="POST" action="processafrm.php?var=10" id="meuform2">
            nome:<br />
            <input type="text" name="nome" size="50" /><br />
            Email:<br />
            <input type="text" name="email" size="50" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enivar dados" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="formulario">
        <form method="POST" action="processafrm.php?var=10" id="meuform3">
            nome:<br />
            <input type="text" name="nome" size="50" /><br />
            Email:<br />
            <input type="text" name="email" size="50" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enivar dados" />
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o pseudo-selector para selecionar ID's começadas com meuform (`^=`) ou até somente `$('form')`.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".resultado").hide();
        $("form[id^=meuform]").ajaxForm({      // ou somente $('form').ajaxForm({
            target: '.resultado',
```

O problema que resta para resolver é:
*como apontar para o `this` dentro da função success?*

Aqui têm duas opções:

### - não usar este plugin

Usar o jQuery `.ajax()` que tem basicamente a mesma funcionalidade, e que neste caso teria uma sintaxe:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        var self = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        var form_data = self.serialize();
        var form_url = self.attr("action");
        var form_method = self.attr("method").toUpperCase();
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: form_url,
            type: form_method,
            data: form_data,
            success: function (retorno) {
                $(".resultado").html(retorno);
                $(".resultado").show();
                self.resetForm();      // aqui é onde resolve o problema
            }
        });
    });
});
```

### - encontrar o `this`

Se bem me lembro esse plugin passa o elemento form como um dos parametros da função. Faça um log da palavra reservada `arguments` para vêr todos os parâmetros da função `success`, julgo que o 4o é o `form`.

```
        success: function (retorno) {
            console.log(arguments);
        }
```

Se encontrar, pode usar assim:

```
        success: function (retorno, status, xhr, form) {
            $(".resultado").html(retorno);
            $(".resultado").show();
            form.resetForm();      // ou talvez $(form) no caso do elemento não vir encapsulado
        }
```

<sub>Se eu estiver errado nesse quarto paâmetro envie pf o link para a documentação desse .ajaxForm</sub>

Comment: Código funcionou perfeitamente e solucionou por completo a questão só fiz uma pequena alteração para dar o reset no form onde era self.resetForm(); ficou assim $(self).resetForm();

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução interessante é criar uma função "genérica" que funciona para qualquer `form` com qualquer campos.

Exemplo:

```
function enviaForm(seletor) {
    var form = $(seletor),
        campos = new Object();

    form.on('submit', function (e) {
        //bloqueia o envio do form, para tratarmos dele aqui dentro
        e.preventDefault();

        //recolhe todos os inputs, desde que não sejam do tipo submit
        $(this).children('input:not([type="submit"])').each(function (i, el) {
            campos[el.name] = el.value;
        });

        //Com os dados todos computados, você faria o AJAX aqui
        $.post('minha-url-post',campos,function(resposta){
            //...
        });

        //limpa o objeto campos para rodar novamente caso necessário
        campos = new Object();
    });
}
```

Exemplo de como chamar a função:

```
enviaForm('.minhas-forms');
```

Para ver ao vivo: [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amh5h/)

O que esse código faz é basicamente gerar um [`Object()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) com todos os dados de um determinado formulário sempre que você der *submit* nele. Com esses dados já no objeto você pode fazer qualquer coisa, no seu caso, enviar via AJAX.

---

**Nota:**

Vale lembrar que este tipo de envio genérico por si só (assim como qualquer código client-side) não oferece segurança real contra pessoas má intencionadas. É altamente recomendável (para não dizer obrigatório) que se faça uma validação dos campos no lado servidor.

Uma boa implementação seria realizar uma validação em JavaScript com mensagens amigáveis para o usuário comum, e no lado servidor realizar a validação contra algum ataque, tratando esta requisição de forma diferente (como por exemplo gravar num log a data e o IP de quem fez a requisição, etc), já que, se o usuário chegou até ali com dados inválidos foi porque ele burlou o JavaScript **intencionalmente** e muito provavelmente está tentando uma invasão.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o `$.each`, referenciando cada form com `this`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form').each(function(){ //para cada form, execute as ações abaixo

           $(this).closest(".resultado").hide(); 
     //como você deve ter vários .closest, selecionamos o mais próximo do form atual

           targetSel = '#'+$(this).attr('id')+' .resultado';
     //criando um novo seletor de alvo, pois o anterior selecionava todos os .resultado da página

           $(this).ajaxForm({
                target: targetSel,
                success: function(retorno){

                     $(this).closest(".resultado").html(retorno);
                     $(this).closest(".resultado").show();
                     $(this).resetForm();
                }
            });
       });

});
```

JQuery [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
JQuery [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)