# Pegar dados de forms

Tags: php, jquery

Como posso pegar os dados de todos os forms existentes em uma página?
Tenho um form com o nome "orcamentos" que consigo enviar os campos mas tenho pelo menos mais três que são inseridos via include e os campos desses forms não estou conseguindo recuperar.

Gostaria de passar todos os campos, independente do nome.

Antes estava fazendo assim:

```
document.orcamentos.submit();
```

Isso envia todos os dados do form com o nome "orcamentos", depois na tentativa de enviar todos os campos independente do nome tentei isso:

```
$("form").submit();
```

Mas envia os campos do form "orcamento" e dos outros inseridos por include não.

Realizando alguns testes percebi que as variáveis que não estão no form "orcamentos" ficam disponíveis e consegui resgata-las via Ajax, como segue:

```
            var sVazaoEta     = $("#Vazao_eta").val();
        var sTipoVazaoEta = $("input[name='TipoVazao_eta']:checked").val(); 
        var sFiltrosEta   = $("input[name='Filtros_eta']:checked").val();
```

Existe alguma possibilidade de passar essas variáveis para a página de detalhes que é acionada pelo submit do do form, pois estou usando o:

```
$("form").submit();
```

Comment: Como faz o envio do form para o lado do servidor? via ajax? E porque não carrega os novos campos para dentro da form existente, sem colocar mais forms na página?

Comment: Os forms que são inseridos via include precisam ser preenchidos pelo usuário e estão no detalhes de uma carrinho de compra, por exemplo ao clicar em "+ Personalizar Orçamento" mostro esse form que são inseridos por include de acordo com a categoria do produto, os campos que estão sendo enviados corretamente são os dados do usuários e estão fora desse carrinho.
Veja essa página, como está:
http://limpida.ind.br/orcamentos.php?add=532

Comment: [Da uma olhada nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19111/um-único-script-para-n-formularios/19119#19119)

Comment: Obrigado @Kazzkig, interessante, mas preciso disparar "todos" os forms em um único botão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o jQuery para serializar os dados de todos os formulários e enviar usando o $.get ou $.post do jQuery

[Nesse link você vai ter informações de como serializar 1 (um) formulário](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)
[Nesse link você vai ter informações de como serializar o formulário no formato array](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) esse é útil, pois você pode adicionar novos elementos ao array, no seu caso os dados dos outros formulários. Você pode serializar para um array o formulário orçamento e adicionar nesse array os dados de todos os outros formulários.
[Nesse link você vai ter informações de como transformar objetos em parâmetros para serem enviados pelo método get ou post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/), isso caso tenha a necessidade de adicionar mais alguma coisa manualmente.
[Nesse link você vai ter informações de como enviar dados usando o post do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
[Nesse link você vai ter informações de como enviar dados usando o get do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: Obrigado @Sileno Brito, vou dar uma estudada nas possibilidades.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o seguinte javascript para enviar os dados de dois ou mais forms:

```
<script language="javascript">
function() submitForms{
  document.getElementById("firstform").submit();
  document.getElementById("secondform").submit();
 }
</script>

<form id="firstform" target="iframe1">
</form><iframe name="iframe1" style="display:none"></iframe>
<form id="secondform" target="iframe2">
</form><iframe name="iframe1" style="display:none"></iframe>
<button onclick="submitForms()"><img src="images/order-button.png" "/></button>
```

Comment: Uma solução interessante @Gustavo Emmel, vou testar essa sua idéia, obrigado.